# How to install TFS plugin on jenkins?

Tags: tfs, jenkins-plugins

I want to install TFS plugin on jenkins but I cannot to do it through Manage jenkins section as my company's network is not allowing me to do it.
Can you please suggest on how I can manually download the plugin and add it on jenkins folder?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about : https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin, then you can try to download the `tfs.hpi` file from [Github (The latest release is currently `5.157.1`)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases/tag/tfs-5.157.1) and then manually install the plugin in Jenkins:

**Manage Jenkins** > **Manage Plugins** > **Advanced** > **Upload Plugin** and select the plugin file downloaded previously (Make sure to have git-plugin installed normally first so all additional dependencies are in place).